# Why requests/Sec is very low in jmeter benchmarking while website serves so many users?

Tags: performance, load-testing

I've created a `Thread Group` to test my server load. In the following picture you can see that throughput is about **27 per min**. The site is a high traffic website. Is jmeter precise on showing this data? How much we can trust it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the beneficial effects of proper cache management and a request which is avoided to the server because the request is either satisfied at the CDN layer or at the local client cache.

Comment: What I meant by the question is that website itself works fast enough, but jmeter shows a very low number!

Comment: requests/sec are a function of the number of requests made.  If you have a high amount of client-side cached items that are requested once per session (or less frequently) then the number of actual requests can be quite low - which is preferred.